# Angularjs - Refresh Control

Tags: angularjs, function

I am a novice, and don't fully understand functions and how/where they are called but I want to refresh a control that has buttons on it that can be enabled/disabled based on state of something else.
The state is determined when the html for that ctrl is loading.
Question is:
For this control, will the reload() command reload only the TaskCtrl, or the entire web page containing all controls? I don't want to reload the entire page.

```
var mainCtrl = angular.module('MyCtrl', []);
mainCtrl.controller('TaskCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$log',
                               function($scope, $routeParams, 
$window,  $location, $rootScope, $log)
{

$scope.loadStuff = function() {
.......
 $scope.studyToken = ret.studyToken;
 $scope.studies = ret.studies;
 $window.location.reload();
}
```

I notice that "loadStuff" function is in another control so I'm assuming that this is a "scope" function that when it executes it can be local in other controls and perform other functions in that control when it executes?

Any suggestions on references for learning these concepts are welcome.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, AngularJs is a Single Page Application (SPA), a SPA loads all HTML templates and javacript code on the first location, you are going to lose state reloading the page, it will be like the first requestion again. Try scope.$apply()

Comment: Ok thanks, yea I really need to get a better understanding of this. A lot of instructionals just don't teach the main concepts, they just have you do examples